# Stress Test - API Gateway + AWS Lambda

Tags: performance, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, stress-testing

I am making a stress test in my system that is designed with AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda.

I am setting 2K Virtual Users each of them making 1 transaction with a Ramp-up of 1 minute.

When making a dummy lambda the system can handle the load.
If I change my lambda to have a `sleep(5)`, I started to see some errors on my dashboard. They're 5xx errors, but there's no logging information on Lambda function. It seems that the Lambda function was not called... The request was "blocked" on API Gateway.

Comment: did you check the apigateway logs? Those logs will tell you why 5xx is happening!

Comment: I have already checked it... Just "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Your Lambda function is probably being throttled, did you check CloudWatch metrics for Lambda?

Answer (score 3):

- There is a possiblility that you are hitting the lambda concurrency limit.[aws lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)
- Each AWS Account has an overall AccountLimit value that is fixed at any point in time, but can be easily increased as needed,As of May 2017, the default limit is 1000 of concurrency per AWS Region.
- Also check the API gateway throttling limits if there are any set at method level for your project (default is 10,000/rps with burst of 5,000) [aws apiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html#apig-request-throttling-account-level-limits)
- Also make sure you inform aws that you are doing a stress test as there is a possibility that they might block you.
- You can have a look at cloudwatch logs for both apigateway and lambdas which might give us some more insight.